# NHibernate - Many to Many relationship - deletion of items

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following schema mapped out in Nhibernate. On Deletion of the Sub Category i would like to delete the category and the event sub category. But the Events are being deleted too. Any clue who i should map this?

Event <--> Event Sub Categories  <--> Sub Categories

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.CalendarEvents).Cascade.All().AsBag().Inverse();
```

Comment: Could you post your mapping between Events and Event Sub Categories please.

Comment: please add the mappings, and perhaps your class structure as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your full mapping definitions but in principle you need to make sure that the mapping definition between `Event Sub Categories` and `Sub Categories` has the `Cascade.All()` or `Cascade.Delete()` option specified (as in your code sample).

However the mapping definition between `Event` and `Event Sub Categories` must have `Cascade.None()` defined. This will prevent nHibernate from cascading the delete of a Sub Category all of the way through to an Event.

Comment: Thanks CSL..it was just what it needed. Cascade.None() on both mappings.